# Switch - case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and then `onOptionsItemSelected` to start a new activity when a specific menu item has been clicked. The code worked properly before adding ABS, and now I get `case expressions must be constant expressions` error on `case`.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about: //error
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.feedback: //error
            //launch activity
            break;

        default:
            break;
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The same code worked fine before adding ActionBarSherlock.

Comment: If you are in a library you have to change all the switch/case statements to if/else blocks from ADT version 14. See: http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields

Comment: Thanks, it works with if/else.

Comment: @dmaxi You should post this as the answer and get credit for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've replaced the `switch/case` statement with `if/else`. You can just click on `switch` and then press `CTRL+1` if you're in Eclipse.

Comment: its a great answer...!

Comment: wowww!! I didn't know about this shortcut
If you know any other shortcut or site from where I can check, Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Posted as an answer as Sam adviced:

If you are in a library you have to change all the switch/case statements to if/else blocks from ADT version 14.

See:

[tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields](http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields)

Answer (score 1):

To switch from the `switch`/`case` statement to `if`/`for`, simply use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> in android studio.

Answer (score -2):

Switch case missing  closing "}".